# Regex : Pattern to match FilePath also matches timestamp

Tags: regex

I am trying to use a regex to find filepath from the log. but it also matches the timestamp.

I am using this pattern : `/(?:\w)[a-zA-Z0-9_./$-](([a-zA-Z0-9_./$-]+ ?)+)*/?`

Suppose the string is : `Date logged on 23/34/12 12:34:12 AM into /asd/asd/sfd`

But it also match the `34/12 12`. How to prevent that from happening. I can do it from code. I want to do it from regex itself.

Comment: It matches `["Date logged on 23/34/12 12", "te logged on 23/34/12 12", "12"]` for that given example. And the last question mark isn't part of the regex i think, or otherwise there is a syntax error.

Comment: @kamilkp: I'm pretty sure the slashes are part of the regex, not delimiters.

Comment: what language u r on??PERL,BASH,JAVA????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be nesting your quantifiers like that - you're making yourself vulnerable to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Second, you will have to think about what exactly distinguishes a file path from a date stamp. The simplest thing I can think of is that the file path needs to start with a `/`, without there being a digit (or other alphanumeric) before that. This can be checked with a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\B`:

```
\B/[\w./$-]+(?: [\w./$-]+)*
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but u can try this out. this will constrain it to have first one to be character instead of digit.

```
/(?:\w)[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_./$-](([a-zA-Z0-9_./$-]+ ?)+)*/?
```

Comment: Why shouldn't a path name start with a digit? (and your regex does nothing to ensure that, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

if your engine support lookbehind:

```
'(?<=into )[\w./$-]+'
```